# Nested forms dynamic adding - recursively rendering rails partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, partial

I'm following the Railscast example for [Nested Model Form](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised). The dynamic adding is possible due to this helper method:

```
def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
    id = new_object.object_id
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
      render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", f: builder)
    end
    link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
  end
```

I am calling this method on the Room association, thus rendering the **_room_fields** partial.
This is all working nicely. The problem is I want to render another fields_for tag with another partial inside that partial.

_room_fields.html.haml:

```
= f.input :dorm
= f.fields_for :beds do |builder|
  =render 'bed_fields', f: builder
```

The problem is my bed_fields partial is not rendering. I've tried putting the same code without it being created dynamically and it renders everything fine. How can I have the second partial be rendered recursively or something?

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured out the problem. The second nested partial wasn't rendering because i hadn't instantiated a new Bed object.